# Одинаковые буквы в начале и конце слова

Tags: javascript

Вводится строка, считаются пробелы и выводится кол-во слов (кол-во пробелов + 1).

> Нужно вывести в консоль слова начинающиеся и заканчивающиеся на одну и
>   ту же букву

```
x = 0;

var str;
str = prompt("Введите строку");

l = str.length;
mas1 = new Array();
mas2 = new Array();
for(i = 0; i <= str.length; i++){    
  mas1[i] = str.slice(i, i+1);
  console.log(mas1[i]);
  if( mas1[i] == ' ' ){ ++x; };
};

console.log('количество слов '+ ++x);    
console.log('количество символов '+l);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если обойтись без костылей, то можно получить вполне себе простое решение. Учитывайте всегда, что строка - это массив символов (работает много где).

```
let str, l, words, needle = 0; // Объявили переменные

str = prompt("Введите строку");
l = str.length;
words = str.split(" "); // Разбили строку по пробелам, получили массив со словами

words.forEach(function(item, i) { // Для каждого слова из массива: если 1 и последняя буква совпадают, тогда считаем
    if(item[0] === item[item.length-1]) needle++;
    console.log(item);
});

console.log('количество слов: ' + words.length); //Сразу посчитали количество слов (значений в массиве)
console.log('количество слов c одинаковой первой и последней буквой: '+ needle); // И выводим

console.log('количество символов: ' + l);
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно за решение, но мне необходимо слова с одинаковыми первой и последней буквами вывести в консоль. В этом и проблема у меня, в массивах не шарю от слова совсем. Если бы был цикл на создание разных массивов из нескольких элементов от пробела до пробела (то есть занести слова в массивы а потом с ними работать, ибо проще).

Comment: @GusGusev, так берёте и выводите `item` в консоль, в чём проблема? Дописал в код.

Answer (score 1):

Слова мы получили

```
let words = [...];
```

Теперь необходимо сгруппировать их по совпадающим первой и последней букве.
Воспользуемся картой (ассоциативным массивом) `Map`, в который, в качестве ключа будем добавлять слово-ключ, составленное из "сцепленных" вместе первой и последней буквы слова из нашего массива, а в качестве значения будет соответствующий массив слов:

```
let map = new Map();

words.forEach( word => {
  // Проверка валидности слова (например, длины)
  ...
  // Ключ = первая буква + последняя
  let letters = word[0] + word[word.length-1];
  if( !map.has(letters ) ) {
     // Инициализируем пару
     map.set(letters, []);
  }

  // Добавляем слово в массив
  let array = map.get(letters);
  array.push(word);

  map.set( letters, array );
});
```

Выводим слова с совпадающими буквами:

```
map.forEach( (array, letters) => {
  console.log(letters + ' -> ' + array); // 'aa' -> ['аа', 'adda', 'asdhfa'] ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = "осел осло лосьон козел лемур ротор";

let bubu = str.split(" ").filter( e => e[0].toLowerCase() == e.slice(-1).toLowerCase() );

console.log( bubu );
console.log( 'Количество: ' + bubu.length );
```

Или

```js
let str = "осел осло лосьон козел лемур ротор";

let bubu = str.split(" ").filter( e => (/^(.).*\1$/i).test(e) );

console.log( bubu.join(', ') );
```

Где `^` - начало строки, `(.)` - любой символ (скобки - группа захвата, на которую позже можно ссылаться), `.` - любой символ, `*` - ноль или сколько угодно раз, `\1` - ссылка на то, что совпало внутри скобок (они должны быть равны), `$` - конец строки.

Подробнее → Поиск «Регулярные выражения»